# Use VBA to insert large XML file into another

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have used VBA to create an xml file and I have another 4mb xml file that I need to add to this. Is there a way to embed the file in excel and then use VBA to attach it to the created XML file?

I need the xml to be part of the excel file so the one that needs to be attached so it can always be found by the program and so that other people who use it don't need to locate the additional file.

If that's not possible, is there a way to have the user browse for the file and then append it before

```
Print #1, "</Folder>"
Print #1, "</Document>"
Print #1, "</kml>"

Close #1
```

Comment: Do you need the XML file to be an embedded *object* in the file, or do you need the XML contents to be literally in the cells of a worksheet?  Or is it more concise to say that you ultimately have *two* XML files and you need to append one to the other?

Comment: I do have two XML files, one created with the VBA program and one that already exists. I need to add the outside file before I put the ending tags on the VBA created XML file.

Comment: OK. I would probably try to work with these two files separately *as XML documents* -- not as XML files opened in an Excel workbook(s). Give me a few and I will put together a brief example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I'm assuming that you have two valid XML files, both with opening/closing XML tags, and that you need to extract the second file's child nodes (all child nodes, so basically the full file *except* for the open/close XML tags) and append to the first file.

This is a simple example, and if you need to append individual child nodes in specific places, you will need to add logic/conditions to do as you need.

Close both files. Open a new workbook and create a vba procedure like so:

```
Sub AppendXMLFiles()
'requires reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0'
'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
Dim file1 As New MSXML2.DomDocument
Dim file2 As New MSXML2.DomDocument
Dim appendNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

'## Load your xml files in to a DOM document'
file1.Load "c:\users\david_zemens\desktop\example xml file.xml"
file2.Load "c:\users\david_zemens\desktop\another xml file.xml"

'## iterate the childnodes of the second file, appending to the first file'
For Each appendNode In file2.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
    file1.DocumentElement.appendChild appendNode
Next

'## View the new XML in the immediate window'
Debug.Print file1.XML

'## Write the combined file to a NEW file'
'   note: if the specified filepath already exists, this will overwrite it'
fso.CreateTextFile("c:\users\david_zemens\desktop\combined xml file.xml", True, False).Write file1.XML

Set file1 = Nothing
Set file2 = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I have already edited out the headers of the second file so it just needs to be inserted in. Would it be possible to have the user browse for the file and then append it before `Print #1, "</Folder>"
Print #1, "</Document>" Print #1, " </kml>"Close #1`in my VBA code. That way it all runs in a single execution

Comment: Sorry, I've just been modifying based on what seems to be the most sane way to implement

Comment: "How can I modify code that *creates* an XML file to add lines from another xml file before the closing </Folder> tag." is a very different question from "how to I append some XML to another XML?"  Yes, it is possible to do what you're asking now... use `FileSystemObject` to read the second file, and insert before closing </Folder> tag.  Please try that, and post your code if you have trouble with it. I'm not writing another answer from scratch.

Comment: The most sane way to work with XML files is with an XML DOM parser :) not to manually break one of the files (by removing the tags) and then try to read it as text and print it in to another file...  My point is that I gave an answer based on the description of the problem, but now you have significantly altered the problem to require a new solution...

Comment: BTW: if this does not actually answer your question (it appears not to...), there is no reason to "accept" it.

Comment: Your answer does work, but I'm trying to make this easier to work with so others can understand how to create this xml file

Comment: I started a new question because my question did change, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938538/print-text-file-in-vba